# How do I debug what packages I'm missing for Linux kernel compilation?

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to compile Linux 4.16 rc6 on my machine running SLES 12 SP 3, with a non-stock kernel.

```
uname -a : Linux sles12m1 4.4.127-2.gf65f3e8-default #1 SMP Fri Apr 13 17:03:37 UTC 2018 (f65f3e8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I copied the config from /proc/config.gz, and provided all the new options required.

Post that, I ran make oldconfig, prepare, and then make, on which I get:

```
└──╼ make
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  DESCEND  objtool
  CHK     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  CC      init/main.o
init/.tmp_main.o: warning: objtool: gelf_getehdr: Request error: not an ELF file
scripts/Makefile.build:324: recipe for target 'init/main.o' failed
make[1]: *** [init/main.o] Error 1
Makefile:1051: recipe for target 'init' failed
make: *** [init] Error 2
```

I've tried Googling around, but no luck. I understand this is some kind of environment issue, but have no idea what it could be.

Any pointers as to how I go about debugging this? I have a fair bit of understanding in these things, so technical answers are more than welcome.

I did face some elfutils issues before I could get make prepare to work as well.

Comment: The file **Documentation/process/changes.rst** in the source describes the tools that you need.